# Getting error Import::chtype when mporting 2D array of images

Tags: import, core-language

Suppose I have

```
images = {{1.jpg, 2.jpg}, {3.jpg, 4.jpg}}
```

Now I try to import all of them at level 2,

```
Map[Import[#], image, {2}]
```

Why does *Mathematica* say there is an invalid file? (error Import::chtype)

Comment: Map[Import[#]&,image,{2}] for starters...

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: you have image one place and images the other. filenames need to be quoted

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
imageFileNameList = {"1.jpg", "2.jpg"};
imageList = (Import[#]&) /@ imageFileNameList
```

In the format you used, the `Import` function was expecting a string and found a list. Be sure to include the path to the files as well.